# Redirecting non www to www in CakePHP using app/webroot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, ubuntu

Gurus of So

I am trying to redirect any user that comes to http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com. I have found a bunch of different ways to do that on SO, but I need to make them fit the dynamic app config from CakePHP.

Currently, this is what my .htaccess reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a Slicehost slice.

Any help is super appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE - SOLUTION - Thanks to Rob Wilkerson

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myapp\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From one of my own apps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.myapp\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: hey there, it does the job but my JS & CSS are all broken now.

Comment: Do you think it could be something to do with index.php?=url=$1 ... line? I don't use that hierarchy in my app.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the comment spam - but it worked! I just replaced index.php?url= to app/webroot/  ! Thank you!